# Replace missing values (given as strings) in pandas dataframe by np.NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a dataframe `energy` with missing values in some column. The missing values are represented by a string `...` in the dataframe. I want to replace all these values by `np.NaN`

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: import numpy as np

In [7]: energy = pd.read_excel('test.xls', skiprows = 17, skip_footer = 38, parse_cols = range(2, 6), index_col = None, names = ['Country', 'ES'
   ...: , 'ESC', '% Renewable'])

In [8]: energy[(energy['ES'] == "...") | (energy['ESC'] == "...")]
Out[8]: 
                          Country   ES  ESC  % Renewable
3                  American Samoa  ...  ...     0.641026
86                           Guam  ...  ...     0.000000
150      Northern Mariana Islands  ...  ...     0.000000
210                        Tuvalu  ...  ...     0.000000
217  United States Virgin Islands  ...  ...     0.000000
```

To replace these values, I tried:

```
In [9]: energy[(energy['ES'] == "...")]['ES'] = np.NaN
/usr/local/bin/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  #!/usr/bin/python3
```

I don't understand the error and also I don't see any other way to achieve what I want to. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, you can pass `na_values='...'` to `pd.read_excel`.

Comment: reopen because `also I don't see any other way to achieve what I want to`

Comment: @jezrael How is that relevant?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seem it is half duplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
energy['ES'] = energy.loc[energy['ES'] != "...", 'ES']
```

Another solution:

```
energy['ES'] = energy['ES'].mask(energy['ES'] == "...")
```

Or:

```
energy['ES'] = energy['ES'].replace({'...': np.nan})
```

But the best is ayhan comment:

> you can pass **na_values='...'** to **pd.read_excel**

Answer (score 0):

If Energy is your pandas dataframe then in your case you can also try:

```
for col in Energy.columns:
    Energy[col] = pd.to_numeric(Energy[col], errors = 'coerce')
```

Above code will convert all your missing values to nan automatically for all columns in your dataframe.